# Modeling a Space Battleship Yamato

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling my favorite anime of all time. The space battleship yamato or Uchuu senkan yamato(japanese).
I'm having some problem on how to model this ship, from the middle part to the front. Especially the front part with those curved and rounded shapes. I've already modeled some beginners and a bit of intermediate objects so I've decided to give this a shot. Any advice would be a big help to me :)
I'll attach my progress pic as well as a reference pic. Thank you in advanced. Stay safe all :)[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to limit the numbers of vertical loop cuts to the same number of vertical lines along side the Yamato hull.

Start with a low poly general shape of the main hull. 
Then start to split / separate the parts as new objects.
Parent everything to the main hull
Hide the main hull and start to develop the other objects into their proper shape.
Some details will be external objects placed along side the hull so don't worry in attempting to model the whole ship from a single mesh.

For the Wave Motion Gun you can use a small cylinder and then Joim the mesh with the main hull, bridging edge loops and creating faces when necessary